# How to create a shortcut to insert a particular string in R

Tags: r, rstudio

For the purpose of uniformity in my code, I repeatedly type four hashes followed by a tab, like this (####    ). Is there a way to create a shortcut key-combination in R/Rstudio where such a string can be defined?

Comment: I don't have the best solution for you, but it might work - you can simply copy this and paste :) Or try inserting comments by ctrl+shift+c

Comment: The customization page does not mention any key bindings. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200549016-Customizing-RStudio

Comment: Why don't you use their named sections feature? Ctrl + Shift + R. This helps navigating your code too.

Comment: Named section feature is good, thanks Ananda for bringing it to my knowledge.

Comment: Ananda, that was such a good feature for you to explain, since I have been like @tavpritesh manually entering lots of sections, can you make an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: Great Ananda. Unfortunately, I have just begun and can't upvote your answer! Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it doesn't answer your question, it might still be helpful for what you are trying to do.

You can organize your code in RStudio using "sections". A typical section looks like this:

```
# Some Section -------------------------
```

These can be manually entered (like the code chunk above, [and with a few other variations](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568)) or you can use the convenient shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

One great result of using these sections is that you can navigate to a particular section by its name, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]